# keyboard.record() append to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append, keyboard-events

I'm trying to record all key-presses until i press space and then comparing the key-presses to a list. I cant seem to find a way to save the recorded keys in a list. And yes I need to use space key not enter submit the input.

```
q = []
rec = keyboard.record(until='space')
q.append(rec)
print(rec)
```

I'm using the keyboard module for this I don't know if there is a better way to do this please share you opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import keyboard
q = []
rec = keyboard.record(until='space')
for key in rec:
    if key.event_type == 'down':
        q.append(key.name)
print(q)
```

keyboard.record store all the keyboard events (both key up and down presses). You could iterate over all the stored key events and store the key down events in your list `q`. Hope it helps!

More information on https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard